# Change Drop area color while file is dragged over the area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put my question as simple as possible.

What I want is that I have created a div droppable div where the particular files can be added. Now what I want is that when I drag a file over the droppable area the color of the div should change.

Its a simple query But I am not able to get it done with My Script.

Here is my Script :

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 targetLayer.ondragover = targetLayer.ondragenter = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  };
  targetLayer.ondrop = function(evt) {
  fileInput.files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  evt.preventDefault();
};

});
```

I just want to add simple CSS when the draggable file is in droppable area.

**EDIT:**

The Target div Id is "targetLayer"

Answer (score 0):

I think this will may work..

**CSS**

```
#targetLayer {
  transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
}
#targetLayer:hover {
  background-color:#d5d5d5;
  transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below snippet which  is taken from [this link](https://www.elated.com/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/)

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #333;
}

/* Give headings their own font */

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

/* Main content area */

#content {
  margin: 80px 70px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Header/footer boxes */

.wideBox {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.wideBox h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* Slots for final card positions */

#cardSlots {
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  background: #ddf;
}

/* The initial pile of unsorted cards */

#cardPile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffd;
}

#cardSlots, #cardPile {
  width: 910px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* Individual cards and slots */

#cardSlots div, #cardPile div {
  float: left;
  width: 58px;
  height: 78px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

#cardSlots div:first-child, #cardPile div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#cardSlots div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}

#cardSlots div {
  border-style: dashed;
}

#cardPile div {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
}

#cardPile div.ui-draggable-dragging {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* Individually coloured cards */

#card1.correct { background: red; }
#card2.correct { background: brown; }
#card3.correct { background: orange; }
#card4.correct { background: yellow; }
#card5.correct { background: green; }
#card6.correct { background: cyan; }
#card7.correct { background: blue; }
#card8.correct { background: indigo; }
#card9.correct { background: purple; }
#card10.correct { background: violet; }


/* "You did it!" message */
#successMessage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 580px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #dfd;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var correctCards = 0;
$( init );

function init() {

  // Hide the success message
  $('#successMessage').hide();
  $('#successMessage').css( {
    left: '580px',
    top: '250px',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  } );

  // Reset the game
  correctCards = 0;
  $('#cardPile').html( '' );
  $('#cardSlots').html( '' );

  // Create the pile of shuffled cards
  var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
  numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the card slots
  var words = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten' ];
  for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}


function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
  // change the card colour, position it directly
  // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
  // again

  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  } 
  
  // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
  // and reset the cards for another go

  if ( correctCards == 10 ) {
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '380px',
      top: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '100px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
  }

}


</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="content">

  <div id="cardPile"> </div>
  <div id="cardSlots"> </div>

  <div id="successMessage">
    <h2>You did it!</h2>
    <button onclick="init()">Play Again</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

The below code provides the color changing effect on while you hover above the dropping area!

```
#cardSlots div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Won't this a mouse hoverring over it, regardless of whether files are added with it?

Answer (score 0):

Call these event where you want to drop file

```
<div class="drag-zone hide_after_paste" ondragover="_ondragover(event)" ondrop="_ondrop(event)" ondragleave="_ondragleave(event)" ondragenter="_ondragenter(event)" >
```

In Javascript use these event as your requirment

```
function _ondrop(e){
  e.preventDefault();$('.drag-zone').css("background", "#ffffff");
}   
function _ondragenter(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('.drag-zone').css("background", "#ffffff");
}
function _ondragleave(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.drag-zone').css("background", "#ffffff");
}
function _ondragover(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.drag-zone').css("background", "#dde5eaaa");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, what we can do is clean up the event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $targetLayer = $("#targetLayer");
  let fileInput = {};

  // On drag over and drag enter, we add a hover class
  $targetLayer.on("dragover dragenter", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $targetLayer.addClass("hover");
  });

  // On drag leave, we remove the hover class
  $targetLayer.on("dragleave", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $targetLayer.removeClass("hover");
  });

  // On drop, we remove the hover class
  $targetLayer.on("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $targetLayer.removeClass("hover");
    fileInput.files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(fileInput);
  });
});
```

This is assuming that the targetLayer is the file input field.

```
<input type="file" id="targetLayer" />
```